# Responsive CSS dot-grid background

Tags: css, svg

I'm wondering if the following is possible:

**A dot-grid as a CSS background, where the column widths are responsive but the dots always stay the same pixel size.**

I've achieved the effect with `linear-gradient` patterns but these do not align with flexbox grids at certain viewport widths – likely due to the pixel rounding using calc() and vw units.

[linear-gradient (Codepen)](https://codepen.io/evvvritt/pen/WdJxbx)

I'm currently looking into using `<svg>` but the problem I'm facing is when the SVG scales, so do the dots (dots should remain the same pixel size as it scales).

I'm worried I may have to resort to HTML elements for the grid and dots :(

Answer (score 0):

Why not adding the dots inside the element using psuedo element and like that thy will always stay at the corners whataver the number of elements:

```css
main {
  margin: 5px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

div {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  height: 150px;
  background: red;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  bottom: -2px;
  right: -2px;
  width: 4px;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 4px, transparent 4px, transparent calc(100% - 4px), #000 90%);
}

div:after {
  right: auto;
  left: -2px;
}

div:nth-child(even) {
  opacity: .5;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>

<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>

<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need them to continue even if an element isn't present. Consider if a row in the flex box ends early because it doesn't have enough items, I need the dots to still complete the grid.

Comment: @evvvvritt ok i understand ... but what is the logic behind this ? you need to visually create a grid and the element will always fit inside if they are present ?

Comment: just how the designer wants it. responsive columns, "dots" are always 2x2 pixels @temani-afif